# Is it necessary to replace "\n" with Environment.NewLine in literal strings used in cross-platform applications?

Tags: c#, cross-platform

Because `Environment.NewLine` has different output depending on the running platform, is it necessary to replace `"\n"` with `Environment.NewLine` in literal strings used in code for cross-platform applications?

For example, I want to show `"Hello World\nI am fine!"`. Should I replace it with `$"Hello World{Environment.NewLine}I am fine!"`? It looks so complicated by the way.

Bonus question: When is the substitution done? At compile time or at run time?

## Edit:

```
class Program
{
    static string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "data.txt");
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = $"I love Xamarin.Forms!\nHow about you?";

        File.WriteAllText(path, input);
        string output = File.ReadAllText(path);

        string[] list = output.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        Console.WriteLine($"words: { list.Length}");
    }
}
```

The output is `words: 1` rather than `words: 2`.

Comment: Nice bonus question (-:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it necessary to replace "\n" with Environment.NewLine in literal strings used in cross-platform applications?

If you want to do cross-platform stuff in general: **yes**.

But... if you are reading from an input stream, of which the formatting is known, or if you are writing to an output stream which expects a specific character, than: **no**.

---

It seems like a lot of work; and it kind of is. But it's good practice and helps to deal with some special file reading cases.

Do note, same accounts for directory [separator chars.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.pathseparator?view=netframework-4.8)

In the case of `/` vs `\`, the usage of platform depending variables is more trivial.

---

As for the bonus question:

If I am not mistaken... They are known by the framework, installed on the machine.

At my windows machine, it's located in: `mscorlib.dll`, and defined as:

```cs
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public static string NewLine
{
  [__DynamicallyInvokable] get
  {
     return "\r\n";
  }
}
```

So, it's build in in mscorelib - which suggests it to be build-time-known. But do note; it's external, so not embedded in your code. It should not be optimized to a constant since it's an external call.

But to be honest.... I need to dig into that.

Comment: In my edit part, could you explain why the output does not follows what you said above that it is not necessary to replace if the string comes from stream?

Comment: Sorry, I think I did not explain myself correctly: I mean; when you are using an external stream, which is out of your control. Like a hardware voltage meter or something; they may fix the new line at `\n` for example. Hope this helps.